# Xcode: Keyboard interrupts a timer function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, multithreading

One of the screens of my iOS app has a textfield and an image which is smoothly rotating around and around via a NSTimer. When I tap the textfield and the keyboard pops up, the rotating image stalls for a fraction of a second. I assume this is because the keyboard code interrupts the execution of the image-rotation code. To solve this, will I have to learn about threading? Or is there a simpler solution?